# How to build a query with MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I need to have a query as such

```
Query.And(Query.NE("name", name[0]), Query.NE("name", name[1]));
```

However I don't know the number of elements in name[] and I need to make a AND of NE of all elements of name[].

Is there a way to build it?

Comment: what tool are you using? (What/where is `Query` coming from?) I'd expect you'd find your answer by searching a little more. Here's a random cheat sheet http://www.layerworks.com/blog/2014/11/11/mongodb-shell-csharp-driver-comparison-cheat-cheet

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm using MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query

Comment: You likely want to be using [`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/#op._S_nin) here instead; that way you don't have to build your query dynamically and it will be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Query.AND()` method signature takes `IEnumerable<IMongoQuery>` parameter type so you could write your method as follows for any number of items:

```
Query.AND(name.Select( x=> Query.NE("name", x));
```